# Transfering my contacts from old phone to a new phone

Tags: contacts, data-transfer

How do I copy all my contacts and messages from my old Android to a new Android phone?

I downloaded Wondershare but the trial version only transfers 1st 5 numbers. Linking the phone to my PC only the SD card details are shown. Contacts and messages may be in the phone memory which I can't access.

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 1):

When you add a new contact, your phone asks you where to store it (Phone, SIM, Google account). **You can store your contacts in your Google account so when you sign in on another device, it will import your contacts.**

For backing up SMS messages you can use **[SMS BackUp+](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zegoggles.smssync)** or a similar app.

For more detailed explanation you can refer to [HowToGeek's article on SMS backup](http://www.howtogeek.com/112852/how-to-backup-your-text-messages-to-your-gmail-account/).

Comment: Not all phones "ask where to store" the contact.

Answer (score 0):

Go to phone dialer menu-> import/export-> export to storage.
After this is done, you can find a file with VCF extension on the SD card.
In the new phone, import the file and select that file from the stored location and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Sign in to your Google account enter your Gmail account on your new phone and all your contacts will appear. Or just import contacts from the SD card on the phone dialer menu